# How can I change the hostname in a URL using Perl?

Tags: perl, url

I have some URLs like http://anytext.a.abs.com

In these, 'anytext' is the data that is dynamic. Rest of the URL will remain same in every case.

I'm using the following code:

```
$url = "http://anytext.a.abs.com";


    my $request = new HTTP::Request 'GET', $url;
    my $response = $ua->request($request);
    if ($response->is_success)
    {
        function......;
    }
```

Now, how can I parse a URL that has dynamic data in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure but is this close to what you're after?:

```
for my $host qw(anytext someothertext andanother) {
    my $url      = "http://$host.a.abs.com";
    my $request  = new HTTP::Request 'GET', $url;
    my $response = $ua->request($request);
    if ($response->is_success)
    {
        function......;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

Otherwise, you can use the [URI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI.pm) class to do url manipulation.

```
my $protocol = 'http://'
my $url_end = '.a.abs.com';

    $url = $protocol . "anytext" . $url_end;
    my $request = new HTTP::Request 'GET', $url;
    my $response = $ua->request($request);
    if ($response->is_success)
    {
        function......;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably enough:

```
# The regex specifies a string preceded by two slashes and all non-dots
my ( $host_name ) = $url =~ m{//([^.]+)};
```

And if you want to change it:

```
$url =~ s|^http://\K([^.]+)|$host_name_I_want|;
```

Or even:

```
substr( $url, index( $url, $host_name ), length( $host_name ), $host_name_I_want );
```

This will expand the segment sufficiently to accommodate `$host_name_I_want`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, like you would parse any other data: Use the information you have about the structure.
You have a protocol part, followed by "colon slash slash", then the host followed by optional "colon port number" and an optional path on the host.
So ... build a little parser that extracts the information you are after.

And frankly, if you are only hunting for "what exactely is 'anytext' here?", a RegEx of this form should help (untested; use as guidance):

```
$url =~ m/http\:\/\/(.*).a.abs.com/;
$subdomain = $1;

$do_something('with', $subdomain);
```

Sorry if I grossly misunderstood the problem at hand. Please explain what you mean with 'how can I parse a URL that has dynamic data in it?' in that case :)